# how to change the position of a canvas object after you created it in Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I was wondering there is a way to directly set the x and y coordinate of a canvas object after you created it. I know `move` method but it only changes the coordinate by the value, but not directly setting it, and I don’t want to make a function just for subtracting the target coordinate by the current coordinate and moving it by the value.

Comment: _" know .move function but it only changes the coordinate but not directly setting it."_ - what do you mean by this? When you call `move`, the coordinates are changed. What more do you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canvas has multiple methods. You can use `coords` to change the coordinates (which can both move and resize the object), `move` to move an item a relative distance in the x and y direction,  `moveto` to move the item to an absolute position.

```
id = canvas.create_rectangle(10,10,100,100)
canvas.move(id, 2, 2)      # move 2 pixels right and down
canvas.moveto(id, 20, 20)  # to rectangle to position 20,20
canvas.coords(id, 100, 100, 120, 120)  # redraw the rectangle at the given coordinates
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.moveto(item_id, x, y)` to move the canvas item to absolute position `(x, y)`.